# Control Variabile Print fron Backend

Tags: magento2, module, custom-variable

I have created a simple extension. In that, I add blocks on the product page.

On the product page, I am printing some variables through a custom file in phtml above the add to cart button. Example:
$Condition
$Guarantee
$Color

Is it possible to manage the printing of variables from the backend?
I would like to have the ability to enable/disable variables
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of Magento modules have the ability to disable them from the backend. Choose any module with that possibility, and copy & modify the necessary files.

In `[yourModule]/etc/adminhtml` create a `system.xml` file and add the following field:

```
<field id="enable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
<label>Enable Module</label> <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Enabledisable</source_model>
</field>
```

In your layout file, add the template you want with the following attribute:

```
ifconfig="[SectionId]/[groupId]/enable"
```

### Edit

If you are trying to disable a single element in your template, you can add a helper class to lookup the status of your backend settings.

```
/* namespace and usings... */
class Data extends AbstractHelper
{

    const VAR_ENABLE = '[SectionId]/[groupId]/enable';

    /* constructor and other functions you want.. */

    public function getVarValue($storeId = null)
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue(static::VAR_ENABLE, ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $storeId);
    }

}
```